# Convert double to 8 length char array in c++

Tags: c++

I want to convert a double to a 8 length char array in c++. The problem is that I want to cover all the number of bytes of the double type (double is not always 8 byte long in c++).

The char array is just used to store the bytes of the double, as if char type = byte type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can always treat any object as an array of bytes. To access the bytes, use a reinterpret-cast:

```
T x;    // any object

unsigned char const * bytes = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>)(&x);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(T); ++i)
{
    std::fprintf("Byte %zu is %02X\n", bytes[i]);   // assuming CHAR_BIT == 8
}
```

Note that there isn't generally a way to know which of the bytes are part of the object representation and what their actual meaning is. For example, a `long double` may on certain platforms have size 12 or 16 but only have 10 relevant bytes, and you don't know which one is which. Though for a `double` with size 8 it's reasonable to assume that there's no padding and that the bytes make up an IEEE-754 representation in linear order. Your platform manual might tell you.

Comment: In order to know how many bytes you need, you can call `sizeof(x)` where x is variable of type double .

Comment: The problem with that is this: Let's say we got a 128 bits double. I want to store just 64 bits, so I need to somehow truncate the double to use only 64 bits. If the double uses IEEE 754 then using the first or the last 64 bits is not really helpful. It is not like using the first or the last bits of an integer, in the IEEE 754 you got a different structure and "spliting" the bits like that would result in a very different number.

Comment: @FlorianPrud'homme: I said that much in the post (`sizeof(T) == sizeof x`), but you don't know what the bytes in the object representation are for...

Comment: @user3313574: You will need to devise your own serialization algorithm that stores an approximation of the `double` value in 8 bytes.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's what I will probably do in the future if I don't find any other solution. By now I think I'll compile the app in VS so assuming 64 bits is fine.